# Image inside divider inherits click

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="div4" onClick="redirect()">
  <img id="img4" onClick="moveToLeft()" />
</div>
```

There's a divider called `div4`, which is clickable, and takes you to a link such as http://google.com, Inside it, there's an image called `img4`, and upon clicking that I want to move it to the left, but clicking it acts as if you were clicking the divider, and takes you to the link. Is there anyway to fix this??

Comment: inside click event in your image click event, add `event.stostopPropagation();` event is the click event parameter

Comment: Didn't work, upon clicking the image it instead gave me an error, and then took me to the link.

Comment: ah typo..`event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` of click event to stop click from bubbling up to div4, something like this:

```
// img4 should be reference to the DOM node
img4.addEventListener('click', (event) => event.stopPropagation())
```

Comment: @Luminous_Dev's solution worked, it was just mis-spelled and i didn't realize that until just now

Comment: @Jacob We answered at the same time and there is nothing preventing you from upvoting both answers, if you like.

Comment: You can upvote his comment and my answer. Technically my answer was the first in terms of completeness as a technical answer. So I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: @Jacob check here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work

Comment: @Jacob it's fine I did